# How can I add CORS support to my REST API in WAS Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

How do I enable CORS support for my REST API.

I found a Jersey specific example here but how do I do this in Liberty/ApacheWink?
[CORS Java server side implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082896/cors-java-server-side-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Inject a HttpServletResponse and issue the desired response headers.  The container does not know the CORS requirement of your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the January 2016 Beta, WebSphere Liberty supports CORS natively. You just configure the server.xml with the CORS options you want, here's an example:

```
<cors domain="/sampleApp/path"
   allowedOrigins="https://alice.com:8090"
   allowedMethods="GET, DELETE, POST"
   allowedHeaders="Accept, MyRequestHeader1"
   exposeHeaders="MyResponseHeader1"
   allowallowCredentials="true"
   maxAge="3600" />
```

The domain attribute is for the application root that you want this configuration to apply to, which means it won't affect any other context roots. The other 7 attributes follow exactly the official CORS spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), so they are pretty self explanatory.

Link to the latest beta: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/